# Building PCL library with GPU/CUDA support

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cuda, cmake, point-cloud-library

I'm building PCL library master in Windows 8.1 using CMAKE:

All other modules are successfully built except the gpu/cuda modules!

Here is the [error log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-sjDPVbvghmNDV1eDZRSWhWWjA/view)

Observation:
-ccbin $(VCInstallDir)bin  -> Environment Variable not set successfully. Due to that this error is Generated: '$' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file? I'm i right? What else could be the problem?

Note that only pcl_gpu_containers module was successfully built.

[image]

Can someone please help me fix this?

```
Version Details: 
Microsoft Visual Studio Verison: 11 (VS Prof 2012) 
cuda toolkit: 7.5 
boost version: boost-1_57 
eigen: 3.3 
VTK Version: 6.2 

PC Info: 
OS Name Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro N 
Version 6.3.9600 Build 9600 
System Type x64-based PC 
Processor   AMD FX(tm)-9590 Eight-Core Processor, 4700 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s) 
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 8.00 GB 
Name    NVIDIA GeForce GT 610 
Adapter Type    GeForce GT 610, NVIDIA compatible 
Adapter RAM (2,147,483,648) bytes 
Name    NVIDIA GeForce GT 730 
Adapter Type    GeForce GT 730, NVIDIA compatible 
Adapter RAM (2,147,483,648) bytes
```

Here is my [CMakeCache.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-sjDPVbvghmRnJjVVBtd2pEdms/view)

Comment: Links to the error log and CMakeCache.txt file seem to be protected.

Comment: oops will update thanks! Updated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC, that issue was related to a missing environment variable setting. 
On my system, this setting was missing after installing CUDA as admin, then working as non-admin user.

After fixing this, now the variables are set as follows:

```
CUDA_PATH = 
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5
```

and

```
PATH =
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\bin;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\libnvvp;
...
```

Comment: Thank you FYI! Could you please tell me What environment variables to change?

Comment: Updated the Question! Could you please clarify please?

Comment: The environment variables PATH and CUDA_PATH need to be set in Windows system control. After that, Visual Studio must be restarted.

Comment: Still getting same error after changing the new Env Variables

Comment: Have you tried re-running CMake, maybe also delete its cache? Sorry that I can't be any more specific, it's some time ago that I had the same issue. All I remember is the env. variables were key to the problem.